# influxdb localhost points the API swagger.json to a path that I cannot serve

Tags: apache, influxdb-2

I installed InfluxDB behind a proxy (Apache) and gave it the following rule:

```
ProxyPassMatch "^influxdb/(.*)" "http://localhost:8086/$1"
```

When I browse the url: mycompany.com/influxdb/docs
it loads with the following error:

```
Something went wrong...
Failed to load https://mycompany.com/api/v2/swagger.json: 404 Not Found

> Stack trace

ReDoc Version: 2.0.0
Commit: 5fb4daa
```

And the reason is because the HTML code behind influxdb is:

```
# curl http://localhost:8086/docs
 
<body>
    <redoc spec-url='/api/v2/swagger.json' suppressWarnings=true></redoc>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/redoc/bundles/redoc.standalone.js"> </script>
  </body>
```

Side note: i think it's also insecure to download this file from the web vs local, and w/o an integrity hash ...

So I'm not sure how to fix and how where to dig for the answer ?

- Either Apache's proxy rule (I'm doing something wrong ?)\
- Change the website's code somehow (couldn't find from where it takes it) but I assume the broken links won't end there ...

Comment: Or maybe, how can I change in the default HTML page the base_url from '/' to something else ?